# Feynman on indefinite integral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Consider:

$$ \int \frac{ \ln (t-1)}{t} dt$$

And then,

$$ I( \alpha) = \int \frac{ \ln [\alpha (t-1)] }{t} dt$$

D.w.r.t. $\alpha$

$$ \frac{dI}{d \alpha} = \int \frac{ 1}{ \alpha t} dt$$

$$ \frac{dI}{d \alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha} \ln t +C \tag{1}$$

Integrating both side with $\alpha$,

$$ I =  \ln \alpha \ln t + C \alpha$$

And putting $ \alpha =1$

I get a weird result...:

$$ I =  C$$

What did I do wrong..? Also is  the constant in (1) a function of $ \alpha$ ..? (generally speaking)

Comment: Is $\int \frac{ \ln t-1}{t} dt = \int \frac{ \ln (t-1)}{t} dt$?

Comment: Yes, all the information here is contained in the $C$. Try and make all the steps explicit when you add bounds to the integral to realize it.

Comment: yes @VIVID that is correct

Comment: @Mindlack Oh, thank you. If you can write this out more concretely as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: How did you get $ \frac{dI}{d \alpha} = \int \frac{ 1}{ \alpha t} dt$?

Comment: Integral is independent of $ \alpha$ , lets me insert the derivative operator into the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the differentiation is where I messed up.

$$ I_{\alpha} = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \frac{ \ln (\alpha (t-1) )}{t} dt$$

Or,

$$I_{\alpha}  = \int \frac{1}{t} dt$$

Hence,

$$ I = \ln t \alpha +C$$

Hence,

$$ \int \frac{ \ln [\alpha (t-1)] }{t} dt  = \alpha \ln t  + C$$

Too bad there is no easy points to evaluate this at >:(